# Getting the most out of AC3's Wolf Pack multiplayer

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I've been really enjoying AC3's new Wolf Pack multiplayer, but it's proving very frustrating. When you get a good game it's brilliant, but more and more games are filled with players who completely miss the point of the game.

To win at Wolf Pack you need to hit a score threshold to get to the next segment and get more time, and your NPC targets spawn infinitely (although always on the far side of the map)

To win you need to get high scoring kills, and quickly, while completing challenges (like 'Get a FOCUS bonus' or 'Get an ACROBATIC kill'). Many challenges involve team work (like SYNC kills which require each assassin to lock a different target) and later segments get tougher - higher score thresholds and targets that hide and defend much better.

The problem is keen (I don't think they're greifing) but confused players that don't understand how the game works at all. Let's call them *Neophyte*.

For instance: I'll set up an INCOGNITO HIDDEN FOCUS POISON OBJECTIVE kill for around 1400pts, and then (before the poison takes effect) *Neophyte* steams in, alerts all the targets and gets a contested 100pts (robbing both my kill score and the 30 seconds or so I spent setting it up). Then a SYNC segment will come up, the other 3 players will set up their targets - *Neophyte* steams in, fails the objective for everyone, sets off a trip bomb and gets themselves stunned.

*Neophyte* will run from one end of the map to the other robbing and generally messing up everyone's kills and ruining any chance of a SYNC or FOCUS bonus for any other players. They'll constantly get caught by smoke bombs and get stunned every other kill, but that doesn't sink into *Neophyte*'s head. They'll average about 150pts per kill.

Usually the game ends the round by about segment 10-12, with *Neophyte* having twice as many kills and half the score that anyone else has.

One of these players will ruin a match and finding a game without them is getting harder and harder.

- Is there any way to kick/ban these players? (I'm sure everyone else will vote with me and they'll learn that they're doing something wrong)
- Is there any way to avoid them?
- If neither of them is possible is there any way to educate these users? (They can already clearly see when other players have a lock, when other players have FOCUS or POISON set)
- Is there some in-game behaviour (they either don't have mics or don't listen to them) that would show them what they're doing wrong?

Comment: Private matchs with friends are the way to go. The missions scale based on the number of players, so you can solo the lowest level difficulty, and a duo can complete the second level difficulty. Avoid public matchmaking, especially on the lowest difficulty. Its also extremely easy to sync your kills when playing alone (Playing with other people in multiplayer is overrated).

Comment: You can never really trust all the players you get matched with, there generally will always be the idiot that just runs around to poke his weapon at everything. If you want to get a decent game, either hope you don't get matched with idiots or play in private games. With the (horrible) matchmaking in the game, you are at its mercy.

Comment: @JoshuaShaneLiberman cheers, but unfortunately my friends are busy with Generic FPS 23, and the SP offers a much better solo experience.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's kind of my point - I realise a private match is one way to avoid the worst players out there, but I'm asking about public matches.

Comment: @Keith - What do you want us to tell you exactly?  You can't control the actions of a player in a non-private match.

Comment: @Ramhound it's more about how to get through to them. They don't seem to notice that when they're playing their team can't complete a round, they must see red notices whenever they get a SYNC KILL FAILED message or fail the current challenge, and they must see that they're bottom of the score board every time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the best way is to just avoid them by playing private matches. In EVERY game, there is *Neophyte* that ruins your 1.5k poison kill.

Most players, when they see *Neophyte* just rage-quit out of the match.

As Joshua stated, missions scale on the number of players, so you might want to consider doing solo wolfpack.

Comment: Yeah, I've played solo and unfortunately most of my friends are playing beige cardboard games like MW, Halo and BF.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I was EXTREMELY frustrated because of these low level new players screwing everything up because they think wolfpack is quantity over quality. I gave up wolfpack and the dreams of dark costumes for a while.

Then one day I did an invite only and invited NO ONE. Solo, I did it. When I realized IT COULD be done solo, I have never gone back since. I have ALL the dark costumes now, solo success first attempt... every attempt.

Solo it. Now, I have only done standard difficulty because I don't think solo is probable on harder levels. But I have never enjoyed wolfpack more since I started doing it ALONE.